# Как вызвать метод getINN

Tags: java, selenium

public static class InnGenerator {

```
    private long inn12;
    private boolean inn_true;
    private  byte[] spep10 = {2, 4, 10, 3, 5, 9, 4, 6, 8};
    private  byte[] spep12_n2 = {7, 2, 4, 10, 3, 5, 9, 4, 6, 8};
    private  byte[] spep12_n1 = {3, 7, 2, 4, 10, 3, 5, 9, 4, 6, 8};

    public boolean isInn_true() {
        return inn_true;
    }

    public long getInn12() {
        return inn12;
    }

    public boolean bool;

    public InnGenerator(long a) {
        bool = this.Check_inn(a);
    }

    public InnGenerator(int i) {
        if (i == 12) {
            inn_true = false;
            while (inn_true != true) {
                inn12 = Inn_12_gen();
                inn_true = Check_inn(inn12);
            }
        }
    }

    private long Inn_12_gen() {
        long gen12 = 100000000000L + (long) (Math.random() * 899999999999L);
        return gen12;
    }

    private boolean Check_inn(long in) {
        String str = String.valueOf(in);

        if (str.length() == 12) {
            int sum_12 = 0;
            int control_number = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < spep10.length; i++) {
                sum_12 = sum_12 + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i))) * spep10[i]);
            }
            if (sum_12 % 11 == 10) control_number = 0;
            else control_number = sum_12 % 11;

            if (control_number == Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(9)))) return true;
            else return false;
        } else if (str.length() == 12) {
            int sum_12_2 = 0;
            int control_number_n1 = 0;
            int control_number_n2 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < spep12_n2.length; i++) {
                sum_12_2 = sum_12_2 + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i))) * spep12_n2[i]);
            }

            if (sum_12_2 % 11 == 10) control_number_n2 = 0;
            else control_number_n2 = sum_12_2 % 11;

            int sum_12 = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < spep12_n1.length; j++) {
                sum_12 = sum_12 + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(j))) * spep12_n1[j]);
            }
            if (sum_12 % 11 == 10) control_number_n1 = 0;
            else control_number_n1 = sum_12 % 11;

            if ((control_number_n1 == Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(11))))
                    && (control_number_n2 == Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(10)))))
                return true;
            else return false;
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

}

Добрый день, есть отдельный класс InnGenerator
Я хочу в другом месте генерировать Inn, как мне его можно вызвать

RandomUtils.InnGenerator innG = new RandomUtils.InnGenerator();

//$("#case_number").val(innG.getInn12);

Comment: Вот зачем в public static class InnGenerator? static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите static в `InnGenerator`.

Создайте объект

```
InnGenerator innG = new InnGenerator(12); 

innG.getInn12()
```

Comment: Что то ему не нравится типа хочет String но на самом деле передается long Required type:
String
Provided:
long

Comment: Идея простая. Нельзя создавать экземпляры статичных классов. Статичный метод должен использовать переменные в параметрах либо статичные поля класса

Comment: Значит ещё то-то там есть. помимо этого вызова

Comment: String.valueOf(innG.getInn12())); Заработало спасибо вам

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов всего 2: либо метод должен быть статический, но тогда из него можно обращаться только к статик полям и методам; или создать объект класса и вызвать метод из созданного объекта.